# SendTwoFactorCodeAsync returning 'UserId not found' after successful login, using SignManager with dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using SignInManager and AuthenticationManager through dependency injection. All working fine except **SendTwoFactorCodeAsync**

Here is the code:

**UtilityConfig**

```
container.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>();
container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

**Account Controller**

```
var myUser = await UserManagerService.Value.FindAsync(model.Mobile, model.Password);
if (myUser != null)
    {
        var result = await SignInManager.Value.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Mobile, model.Password, false, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
             case SignInStatus.Success:
              {
                  //success code 
              }
             case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
              {
                    var code = await UserManagerService.Value.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(myUser.Id, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhoneCodeProvider"]);
                    var send = await SignInManager.Value.SendTwoFactorCodeAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhoneCodeProvider"]); //here throughing exception
                    if (send)
                       {
                            SmsHelper.Value.SendSmsBySmsBatch(user.UserName, Constant.Instance().ProductName, myUser.UserName, "Code is " + code, true);
                            return RedirectToAction("TwoFactorCode", new { Provider = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhoneCodeProvider"], ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
                       }             
              }
              break;  
              ---------------                              
                        }
```

Also tried this:

```
var userId = await SignInManager.Value.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync(); // this is returning 0
    var user = await UserManagerService.Value.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    if (user != null)
    {
       var code = await UserManagerService.Value.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(myUser.Id, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhoneCodeProvider"]);
       var send = await SignInManager.Value.SendTwoFactorCodeAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhoneCodeProvider"]); //here throughing exception
       if (send)
          {
              SmsHelper.Value.SendSmsBySmsBatch(user.UserName, Constant.Instance().ProductName, user.UserName, "Your security code is " + code, true);
              return RedirectToAction("TwoFactorCode", new { Provider = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhoneCodeProvider"], ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
          }
    }
```

strange thing is that on first try I get this issue and on second try it works fine (return all results perfectly) .. again I logout and try .. first time get issue second try it works .

Not able to track the reason of this failure, what can be the best way to solve this

Answer (score 1):

I get the exact same error. I tried adding case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification: Thread.Sleep(500)
to see if it was just a delay but to no avail.

It requires a redirect as the SendTwoFactorCodeAsync checks to see if Request.IsAuthernticated. Which the request is not, but there is a valid log in.

It is a bug and should be reported on github

Comment: I tried the redirection.. but the problem is .if I refresh the url (the one I have redirected on to get code as input) .. it resend the verification sms ... not safe at all ..

Comment: Yes this method relies on a cookie from password sign in, so it won't work until the next request, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity for how its was typically used

Comment: its not exactly straight forward but there is a workaround , see my code below

Comment: As @HaoKung mentioned, I solved a related problem by enabling the application to temporarily store user information when verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process. In my startup class:   app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

Answer (score 0):

here is my code:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email.Trim(), model.Password.Trim(), model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                var userId = await SignInManager.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync();
                if (userId == null)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("redirectSendTwoFactorCodeAsync", "Account",
                        new
                        {
                            ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
                            Email = model.Email,
                            Password = model.Password,
                            RememberMe = model.RememberMe
                        });
                }

                if (!await SignInManager.SendTwoFactorCodeAsync(twoPartCode))
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failure sending Email verification token");
                    return View(model);
                }
                return View("VerifyCode", new VerifyCodeViewModel { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> redirectSendTwoFactorCodeAsync(string ReturnUrl, string Email, string Password, bool RememberMe)
    {
        if (!await SignInManager.SendTwoFactorCodeAsync(twoPartCode))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Failure sending Email verification token");
            return View("Login", new LoginViewModel()
            {
                Email = Email,
                Password = Password,
                RememberMe = RememberMe
            });
        }
        return View("VerifyCode", new VerifyCodeViewModel { ReturnUrl = ReturnUrl, RememberMe = RememberMe });
    }
```